# What is this syntax exactly doing?

Tags: javascript

What is exactly happening in the following line?

```
return [selector, operation || "=", true];
```

I understand what returning is, the OR operator, etc. I've never seen this exact syntax.

Comment: It's an array literal. You seem to know the components, right?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. It's obvious that the poster is curious about the code and is trying to learn. I thought that's why we're all here.

Comment: The elements of an array literal can contain expressions. The value assigned is the result of evaluating the expression.

Comment: It sounds like you understand what the syntax means, but not why it was used. For that, you need to give us some context.

Answer (score 3):

It means:

> Return an array of 3 elements: `selector`, `operation` (unless it's [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), then `"="`), and `true`.

Comment: You mean when falsy it is going to be a `=`, right?

Comment: Wow. Seems so simple, like why wouldn't i know this. Long day. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The line is parsed with the || operator binding tighter than the separating commas. So the line is equivalent to `return [selector, (operation || "="), true];`

In javascript, the `||` operator doesn't just work with boolean values. The actual semantics for `return (a || b)` is: "if (a is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)) return a; else return b;".

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR